# ItextSharp modify takes time

Tags: c#, service, itext, itext7

I have a pdf template and I want to add an "option action" to that template, this should be done for all of the Recipients I have, which they're 4000.

This means I should end up with 4000 pdf files for each recipient.
But it takes a very long time, approx 500 files/12 mins.

Note: the template size is 340 KB

I built a windows service to do this job, and this is the code that does the job:

```
private static byte[] GeneratePdfFromPdfFile(byte[] file, string landingPage, string code)
{
    try
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var reader = new PdfReader(file);
            var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms);
            string _embeddedURL = "http://" + landingPage + "/Default.aspx?code=" + code + "&m=" + eventCode18;
            PdfAction act = new PdfAction(_embeddedURL);
            stamper.Writer.SetOpenAction(act);
            stamper.Close();
            reader.Close();
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}



public static byte[] GenerateAttachment(AttachmentExtenstion type, string Contents, string FileName, string code, string landingPage, bool zipped, byte[] File = null)
        {
            byte[] finalVal = null;
            try
            {
                switch (type)
                {
                    case AttachmentExtenstion.PDF:
                        finalVal = GeneratePdfFromPdfFile(File, landingPage, code);
                        break;
                    case AttachmentExtenstion.WordX:
                    case AttachmentExtenstion.Word:
                        finalVal = GenerateWordFromDocFile(File, code, landingPage);
                        break;
                    case AttachmentExtenstion.HTML:
                        finalVal = GenerateHtmlFile(Contents, code, landingPage);
                        break;
                }
                return zipped ? _getZippedFile(finalVal, FileName) : finalVal;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }
```

the GenerateAttachment Method is being called for each Recipient because the action is based on the recipient's id, and I'm using this approach to iterate through the List to speed up the process

```
 Parallel.ForEach(listRecipients.AsEnumerable(),
                 new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount * 2 },
                 (item) =>
                    {                      

         File.WriteAllBytes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Attachments\" + group.Code + @"\" + item.Scenario.CampaignCode + @"\" + item.CMPRCode + "." + extension,
                            GenerateAttachment(_type, value, item.AttachmentName, item.CMPRCode, item.Scenario.LandingDomain, item.Scenario.AttachmentZip.Value));

                    });
```

Comment: Paralleling your IO probably won't help unless you're reading from multiple devices simultaneously. A device can usually only read one stream of data at a time, so you'd just be blocking on the OS/BIOS level instead of the thread level. The thread would then be left waiting on the IO to complete, and you'd just have a bunch of `Thread`s lying around not doing anything.

Comment: Also, how many unique files are you dealing with? (input, not output)

Comment: I would imagine running this single threaded would have a slightly faster run time (very slightly), and lower memory consumption (due to not having as many `Thread` instances. I could be way off, though. As for making this *faster*, I'm wondering how many unique input files you're dealing with.

Comment: @cwharris so, you mean using single threaded loop is better? or any other suggestions to accomplish this? i'm dealing with one file "input" or maybe many files - because each recipient may belong to same/different campaign which means different input file

Comment: You're dealing with only a few unique files, but you're reading the file from the system each time you use it. Perhaps caching the files could reduce run time?

Comment: Also, I don't see a reason for `GC.Collect` here. That'll run automatically when memory gets low. Running it manually has very few use cases. Reducing jitter in a video game after level loading, for instance. Running it here when you're only doing file manipulation seems unnecessary.

Comment: what do you mean by caching the file? i mean in coding wise

Comment: Instead of reading the file from disk each time you need to use it, you could instead keep a copy of it in memory. IO is generally very slow in comparison to processing. In your case, a `Dictionary<string, byte[]>` might work, though that's a very naive cache.

Comment: oh! this is exactly what I'm doing, because the file is being loaded from a DataTable as byte[], i'm only saving it locally after adding the "action" into it

Comment: I suggest profiling the code to see where the hot spots are, and working from there. https://www.nprofiler.com/